# Device enumerator - DeviceWatcher for windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, device

I would like to enumerate all devices connected in my system when my app starts
and whenever any devices are connected or added or removed the app should be notified.

In windows 8 client we have the `devicewatcher`, is there anything similar for windows 7 as my app or client would be installed on win 7?